# python elegant bypass to not having locale.D_T_FMT on windows

Tags: python, datetime

Here's the deal. I have a tool written in C# (not mine, can't change it) that among other things prints to the log time and date in the current locale.
So far so good...
I want to write a python code that parses this.
the "correct" way is giving `datetime.strptime` the `locale.nl_langinfo(locale.D_T_FMT)` as a format string.
But alas! I'm on windows (in which the locale object has no D_T_FMT)
Any elegant way to bypass this?

Comment: nothing elegant, sorry. Personally, I would adapt the [linux format string](http://ideone.com/JKLXxL) to your date format. More details on the fields  [in the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

Comment: yeah... but I need to write a utility that works on each machine (which can be different)

Comment: I have the same issue, still Google'ing it